# How to print out an array of user inputs in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, user-input

Currently my code will print out what ever the user types into the input box after they have submitted it. If I type 'Dave', that gets printed out. If I then type 'Paul'. Paul replaces where Dave has been outputted. I want a way where if I type out another name instead of replacing it, it will print it out underneath, unlimited times. I am thinking of using an array instead of the current string but not sure how to do this. here is my code so far:

```
var ToDoForm = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
      return {text: '', submittedValue: ''};
    },
    handleChange: function(event) {
      this.setState({text: event.target.value});
    },
    handleSubmit: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.setState({submittedValue: this.state.text});
      console.log("ToDO: " + this.state.text);
    },

    render: function() {
      return (
          <div>
            <h1> todos </h1>

            <form className="todoForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Type out a task"
                  value={this.state.text}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
              <input
                  type="submit"
                  value="Submit todo"
                  />
            </form>

            <h2> Data should appear here </h2>
              <p>{this.state.submittedValue}</p>
          </div>
      );
    }

  });
```

So far `text` gets assigned to `submittedValue` and then submitted value is what gets printed out.

I have started with this

```
getInitialState: function() {
      return {text: '', submittedValue: []};
    },
```

but now I am stuck as to what to do next

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once `sumittedValue` is an array in state.  You should be able just to `push` to it:

```
handleSubmit: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.state.subittedValue.push(this.state.text);
      this.setState({submittedValue: this.state.subittedValue});
      console.log("ToDO: ", this.state.submittedValue);
    },
```

Of course then you have to loop through the array (`map`) in order to render:

```
<h2> Data should appear here </h2>
{this.state.submittedValue.map(
    function(value, i) { 
        return (<p key={'val-' + i}>{value}</p>);
    }
)}
```

`key` is required to uniquely identify the looped `<p>`.  Otherwise, a warning would show on render.

Comment: Good answer. Also, this.setState in the handleSubmit is important. The push is not enough to trigger the render. You might want to emphasize that.

Comment: this seems good but I have a question. where you have the `<div>`, I want `<p>{listItems}</p>`. how do I then extract your `<div>` content and put this into the render return part?

Comment: @TheHurricane you shouldn't *need* the `<div>` if you don't want it.  But you do need the map.  I made an edit and took out the `<div>`.

Comment: it will show warning in the console because of key is not set for p tag, actually its important while writing in reactJS